# Integrate nested SELECT query when querying for objects in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-database

Say I have a table Table1 constructed similar to below, where * is Key

```
ID*   GROUPID*    ATTR1      ATTR2  (...additional columns)
--    -------     -----      -----
1       100        45         89
2       100        37         27
3       101        69         19
4       102        37         22
```

And given a pair of values for ATTR1 and ATTR2, I want my query to return a list of all rows that belong to the GroupID for a given ATTR1 and ATTR2's GROUPID. Assume for each pair of ATTR1 and ATTR2 will have zero or one GroupID.

Is there a way to formulate this query to not have a nested query (and therefore speed it up)? Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT [GROUPID], [ATTR1], [ATTR2]
FROM [TABLE1]
WHERE [GROUPID] = (
    SELECT TOP 1 GROUPID
    FROM [TABLE1]
    WHERE (ATTR1 = @attr1) and (ATTR2 = @attr2)
);
```

Comment: The subquery is not correlated to the outer query AFAIK, so this might run faster than you think.

Comment: You've marked one column, `groupid`, as the primary key, but the data contains two rows with the same group ID value — which means it is _not_ the primary key.  You should probably show a few more lines of data, and clarify what is the primary key, and also show the expected output from the sample data you show.

Comment: You're right, there's another column (ID) that also forms the primary key. I've updated the question, although I think Gordon managed to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be fine.  However, you can guarantee one execution of the subquery by moving it to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT t1.GROUPID, t1.ATTR1, t1.ATTR2
FROM TABLE1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 1 GROUPID
      FROM [TABLE1]
      WHERE (ATTR1 = @attr1) and (ATTR2 = @attr2)
     ) tg
     ON t1.GROUPID = tg.GROUPID;
```

For performance, you want two indexes:  `TABLE1(ATTR1, ATTR2, GROUPID)`, and `TABLE1(GROUPID)`.